# Packagist prefixes branch names with dev-

Tags: git, github, composer-php, packagist

Packagist.org prefixes my branches with 'dev-' which I don't wan't it to do, since I've a dev-master and a master branch in my repo. Any trick to not have it prefixed?

[Packagist page](https://packagist.org/packages/visalogic/api)

[Github repo](https://github.com/VisaLogic/api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create a `dev-master` any* branch as branches will automatically appear as "dev" versions in Packagist.

*any branches except branches named like versions (e.g. if the branch name is 2.0)

New versions of your package are automatically fetched from **tags** you create in your github repository.

So if you specify a version when you require your package it fetches from the `master` branch the latest **tagged** version.
e.g. `"acme/package": "3.2.x"` takes the latest `3.2` tagged version from the `master` branch.

If you need the latest `dev` version which is still untagged in your master branch then you can require `dev-master` in the `composer.json`. E.g. `"acme/package": "dev-master"` which fetches the latest commit from your `master` branch.

For more Info see: https://packagist.org/about#managing-package-versions or https://getcomposer.org/doc/02-libraries.md#branches